# How do I recognize bad recruiters who only want my data?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

Not a week goes by without me being contacted by recruiters on linkedin or other networks. The first time I was still very enthusiastic. Talked to the woman for almost an hour, sent her my CV and then never heard from her again.

From the comments I have read here in the last weeks this is apparently not unusual. Some people just want a full database, but don't help much.

How do you recognise these people?

Are there any questions I can ask to discover their true intentions? I feel that if I talk to everyone, it would just be a waste of time.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only person that feels this way!  Once they get your phone number, email, resume or whatever, they go dark.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you recognize these people?

Do they have a pulse? If so, they're one of those people. They care not one iota about you. If you're actually looking for a job then engage with them. If you aren't, then don't.

I personally don't spend any time engaging with recruiters that cold call me. If I receive an email about a position that I think I may be interested in I ask them what the hourly rate or salary is. If it's not within my acceptable range I tell them so and tell them I'm not interested. If it is, then I'll go further in having a conversation with them.

Not engaging with them is not going to hurt your prospects in the slightest. They have 100 other people to cold call. Next month they'll go back to the beginning and start all over again.

Comment: Ha so true.  I started looking at my Inmails and one guy mesaged me in march, then may, then aug, basically with the same message.    Brokers are so usless, if there is any industry to "disrupt" it's any industry with brokers as there's nothing a centralized/electronic market place can't do that a broker can.

Answer (score 2):

1. If they ask for your birthday
2. If they ask for any Personally identifiable information
3. if they ask for your social security number
4. If they ask for your skype ID
5. If they are particularly aggressive
6. If they don't have a specific job in mind for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Ask the recruiter about the opportunities they have for you**, and ask them early in the conversation.

If they have one or more positions to talk about, then great. If they don't then you can end the call.